# How can I programmatically download data from QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

Is there a way to download query results from the database such as tables or other datasets? The UI supports a CSV file download, but this is manual work to browse and download files at the moment. Is there a way I can automate this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [export REST API endpoint](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest#exp---export-data), this is what the UI uses under the hood. To export a table via this endpoint:

```sh
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=select * from my_table" http://localhost:9000/exp
```

`query=` may be any SQL query, so if you have a report with more granularity that needs to be regularly generated, this may be passed into the request. If you don't need anything complicated, you can redirect curl output to file

```sh
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=select * from my_table" \
http://localhost:9000/exp > myfile.csv
```